# How to read large excel files from FTP server using apache-poi efficiently?

Tags: java, excel, ftp, apache-poi, sftp

I want to read large excel file(.xls) with 300k records with file size up to 300 MB. After reading I want to load that data in db table.

I wrote a normal poi code to read xls file from the local machine. I ran that code against excel file with around 60k records and it worked perfectly fine. also i wrote code to get inputstream from ftp and ran the code it worked fine, but when i ran the same code (on local) with file with 200k+ records it gave me some system gc memory is full error. I haven't tried running that code with 200k records from ftp server.

which way to use to read file from FTP server?
I have also seen lines of code on internet below:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/workbook.xlsx")); 
Workbook workbook = 
StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100).bufferSize(4096).
sheetIndex(0).open(is);
```

But above line of code give me workbook object. I want an XSSFWorkbook object.

Comment: Do you have file to test, can you put in some location so that we can try ?

Comment: If the same file opens fine locally, why not split your code into two steps? One to download from FTP to a temporary file, one to read the spreadsheet from the temp file?

Comment: i do not have the file with me file is confidential.

Comment: @Gagravarr i will try that. but mostly what client need is not to download but to read directly  but lets see

Comment: but downloading will take time thats why we decided to stream directly

Comment: Apache POI needs the whole file. Whatever you do, the whole file is getting downloaded before any processing happens. Either you download it to a temp file, or Apache POI downloads it into memory. If you want a streaming format, try CSV!

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr i tried it using xlsx-StreamReader it does not load the whole fie and creates temp file i dont know how it works. but the drawback of xlsx-Streamreader is that it replaces Cell with StreamingCell so you can not use many of the methods that poi CELL offers. also you can not use specific Cell or Workbook like XSSF or HSSF workbook